# Recursively removing the adjacent duplicates

Tags: java

The problem is to remove the adjacent duplicate elements from the string.After executing for one time it is giving the

> java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range:
>   14

I tried debugging but the code execution ends immediately after going through first recursion.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class RemoveAdjacent {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String s = "geeksforgeeks";
        removeDuplicate(s, 0);
    }

    public static void removeDuplicate(String d, int i) {
        int n = d.length();
        if (d.charAt(i) == d.charAt(i + 1) && i <= n) {
            d = d.substring(0, i) + d.substring(i + 1, n + 1);
            i = i + 1;
            removeDuplicate(d, i);
        } else if (i <= n) {
            i = i + 1;
            removeDuplicate(d, i);
        } else {
            System.out.println(d);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

```
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1963)
String.java:1963
    at RemoveAdjacent.removeDuplicate(RemoveAdjacent.java:16)
RemoveAdjacent.java:16
    at RemoveAdjacent.removeDuplicate(RemoveAdjacent.java:21)
RemoveAdjacent.java:21
    at RemoveAdjacent.main(RemoveAdjacent.java:10)
```

Comment: don't vote down the question.I was unable to find the error and wanted to know the correct reason.

Comment: your question belongs to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ if you ask me, hence the downvotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were very close but a few things needed to be fixed.

- You needed to reorder your if-statement so that the bounds are checked properly.

  **Note**: The reordering isn't strictly necessary, but it makes the base-case for your recursion more clear.
- You won't want to do `d.substring(i + 1, n + 1)` in your first if statement. That would be saying:

  > give me the string from `i + 1` to the `end + 1`

  Which woudn't be valid. You can just leave out the second parameter and it will use the end automatically.
- If the current character equals the next character, you want to remove the character but not increment `i` as a new character has just taken the previous ones` place and now needs to be checked.

Something like this should work:

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "gggggeeksfooorrrrgggeeeeksssss";
        removeDuplicate(s, 0);
    }

    public static void removeDuplicate(String d, int i) {
        int n = d.length();
        if (i >= n-1){
            System.out.println(d);
        } else if (d.charAt(i) == d.charAt(i + 1)) {
            d = d.substring(0, i) + d.substring(i + 1);
            removeDuplicate(d, i);
        } else{
            i = i + 1;
            removeDuplicate(d, i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: After executing for 1 time the code gets terminated at the line:`d = d.substring(0, i) + d.substring(i + 1, n + 1);`.Would like to know why this was happening with my code?

Comment: My second bullet point talks about that. The length of the string is `n`. In the second half of the expression, you try to grab the string from `i` to `n+1` which means you're trying to grab the characters from `i` to the end of the string, `n`, and then one more character after that. There are no characters after the end of the string and therefore an StringIndexOutOfBoundsException is thrown because `n+1` is "out of the bounds of the string".

Answer (score 1):

Probably, you should take a look at what `substring` method does. [Link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)) to the method signature.

If you notice, the second argument is the end index (exclusive). At line 16, you have provided the second argument as `n+1` which will always be out of bounds. Either you can provide the second argument as `n` or just don't provide the second argument in which case the [method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)) will be called. Moreover, the check at line 15 is incorrect. Something like the code below will work:

```
public static void removeDuplicate(String d, int i) {
    int n = d.length();
    if (i+1 < n && d.charAt(i) == d.charAt(i + 1)) {
        d = d.substring(0, i) + d.substring(i + 1);
        removeDuplicate(d, i);
    } else if (i <= n) {
        i = i + 1;
        removeDuplicate(d, i);
    } else {
        System.out.println(d);
    }
}
```

Note that line 17 in your code is not needed as that would result in just removing the adjacent duplicate character and the subsequent duplicate characters. Also, there is no need for the `return` statement in the `else` block. Hope, this helps.